# Cold streams and publishers, is the Garbage Collector fully aware of its true death?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, reactive-programming, publish-subscribe, self-reference

```
    final Consumer<T> localConsumer = this::accept;
    insatnceSubscriptorManager.baseSubscribe(
            isActive -> {
                if (isActive) publisher.add(localConsumer);
                else publisher.remove(localConsumer);
            }
    );
```

When `instanceSubscriptorManager` is unable to receive any more boolean values, the last thing to be performed will be a `false` as isActive, removing `localConsumer` from `publisher`.

How is `localConsumer` "aware" that `instanceSubscriptorManager` will be unable to receive an isActive -> true (again) sometime in the future, especially since the class is self-referencing itself?

In short, this class is hold by both ends, the `this::accept` hold by the `publisher` which in turn is hold by `this.insatnceSubscriptorManager` receiving trues or falses.

This tells me that the JVM must create an index of references that is not looking at things from an OOP perspective, instead it treats all variables, local or instanced as independent nodes.

If the "thing" that delivers `instanceSubscriptorManager` trues or falses gets GC'd, is it reason enough for the Garbage Collector to determine that the references captured by the baseSubscribe interface should no longer be captured, freeing the publisher in the process?

****OR should we still need to execute an `unsubscribe()` manually?****

I wonder if there's a limit to the "depth" of the collected branch, How many subscribers/Consumers could be linked to one another until the GC can no longer detach them all if a node get's detached?

Comment: Is “*If the ‘thing’ that delivers `instanceSubscriptorManager` trues or falses*” the only thing that has a reference to `instanceSubscriptorManager`?

Comment: Yes, @Holger, there are 2 types that may interact with (captures) instanceSubscriptorManager, one of them is another instanceSubscriptorManager, and the other, is a self-detach-able eventListener.
You may think of this "self detachers", as the exit point (leafs) between my design and what's already part of the old architecture.
After placing some logs in the finalize() of each Subscriber I could confirm that they were in fact being GC'd after the leaves were detached.

Comment: If the leaf (self-detachable eventListener) of a single file (forkless branch) of subscribers, appended one after the other, gets detached, ALL of them get GC'd up to a point where a fork is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you wrote it? `publisher` is stick and never gets GCed.

The cheap fix is to 'just call `unsubscribe` in a timely fashion', but that will probably sound about as useful to you as telling a leg amputee to just 'grow the leg back'.

You *can* have a system that will 'auto unsubscribe' an event listener at the appropriate time based on GC eligibility of objects.

### Why can `publisher` not be GCed?

If you're already clear on this and just needed it confirmed, scroll to the next section.

The `publisher` variable is cloned. That's why any variables you use in lambdas are required to either be declared `final` or 'effectively final' (meaning: If you shove `final` on it, it wouldn't be a problem, in which the compiler will do that for you). Just making copies of things that change would be highly confusing.

Thus, The lambda here (everything from `isActive ->` to the end of the brace) is, for GC purposes, encapsulated in an object, and a ref to whatever `publisher` is pointing at is part of this object. As in, it has a field, with that value.

This object is then handed to the `baseSubscribe` method.

Assuming that:

- `instanceSubscriptorManager` is pointing at an object that is not eligible for GC.
- You can 'get' from that object (via its fields, whether code exists anywhere in the runtime that actually does this is irrelevant) to the handler, and thus from there to `publisher`.

Then, voila - GCing of whatever publisher is pointing at will now never happen. It's 'stuck', due to being perenially reachable from `instanceSubscriptorManager` which we just axiomatically stated isn't going away. (However, if publisher is the *only* way to get to `instanceSubscriptorManager`, and `instanceSubscriptorManager` is the *only* way to get to `publisher`, there's no problem here - java does not suffer from the inability to clean up cyclic orphan chains, unlike, say, Apple's refcount GC impl for ObjC and, I think, swift).

### Smart unsubscribe sounds awesome. What's that about?

This (management of fleeting event handlers) is an intractably hard problem that just about every event system out there 'solves' by offering you a `subscribe` method, an `unsubscribe` method, and a sincere wish for good fortune and luck. You figure out how to manage it with those 2 primitives, that's all you get.

Which, for many application domains that want to employ fleeting handlers ('fleeting' as in: You'd like for them to be eligible for GC, and you make an infinite amount of them if the app runs forever) - **sucks**.

One obvious reason that the `unsubscribe` part feels so cruddy is that most app domains simply do not have fleeting handlers. The amount of times `.subscribe()` is invoked for the lifetime of an app is a constant value, and the handler objects you pass to the event source are *intended* to live forever.

But when that is *not* what you want, as you appear to run into here (i.e., you want fleeting handlers), it's vastly more convenient to use the tools in the `java.lang.ref` package: WeakReferences and reference queues.

See, you can subscribe to java's own GC system! You can turn an object into a soft or weak ref (the difference? The javadoc will explain, it gets a little complicated. You probably want Weak), and then ask the GC system if the object it would be pointing at is GCed or not, and even ask to be notified once it is.

This gets to a different paradigm for subscribe/unsubscribe. Instead of:

1. Subscribe to receive event notifications (and in passing, lock that object in as not GC-able, as it is reachable by the event source now), and
2. When you no longer want that, call `unsubscribe` and this will also relinquish the reachability from the eventsource to the object; it will no longer impede GC

you can do a much better job. Simply do:

1. Subscribe to receive event notifications, but also pass along a 'watch'. The event source holds a weak reference to the watch (See below) object and will automatically unsubscribe the event handler once the watch object is GCed. Because it knows about the watch via the weakref indirection, the event source is not impeding GC eligibility of the watch. It's up to the code that wants to subscribe to events to ensure that the watch cannot be GCed until you *want* to stop receiving notifications. This system is also nebulous as to when you stop receiving events: Java does not **instantly** mark an unreachable object as eligible for GC, nor can it fire the refqueues to inform anything keeping track of the GC-ability of the watch in an instant fashion. It'll get around to it.
2. ... there is no step 2. Unsubscribing just happens, just when you'd want it to.

In particular, you have the concept of a [`java.lang.ref.WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), which lets you apply a layer of indirection and disconnect the referencability chain:

```
class SomethingLongLived {
   private final Object field;

   void code() {
     field = new Object();
   }
}
```

In the above, that object we make can't be GCed until the instance of `SomethingLongLived` goes away, which for the purposes of these examples, it won't. But now it can be:

```
class SomethingLongLived {
   private final WeakReference<Object> field;

   void code() {
     field = new WeakReference<Object>(new Object());
   }
}
```

The WeakReference object itself *cannot* be collected of course, but the general idea is, a WeakRef object is itself tiny, and presumably the object you're interested in is either huge, or you are interested in it solely to keep track of whether it is eligible for GC or not. You can ask a WeakReference object for the 'referrant', but that will return `null` if the referrant is already GCed or in the final phases (one of the last things that happens to an object before the memory it occupied is truly marked as 'free', is that any `WeakReference` links to it are nulled out. After that, there isn't any way to get at that object, period).

Your event firing code can be as simple as checking the associated weakref first. If it is null, do *NOT* send the event to the associated eventhandler, and remove the weakref+eventhandler pair from the list of handlers.

Note that it can still be complicated: If the eventhandler itself has a way to reach the watch object, then **they never ever go away**: The event source can reach the handler, the handler can reach the watch: Nothing ever gets GCed. Watch management is therefore a bit tricky sometimes.

You can, if you want, simplify this system by making the event handler itself the watch - the event source doesn't prevent GC of any of the handlers subscribed to it; that'd be the responsibility of callers. But in practice this doesn't work out nicely, and you're at significant risk of creating a chain that then prevents all GCs. Much better to have trivial watch objects (literally trivial: `new Object()` - its only purpose is for the event source to observe whether it's been GCed), and find a place to store a ref to this thing, so that 'if that place gets GCed - the watch goes with it, and the event handler is unsubscribed automatically as well'.

For what its worth, I am not aware of any event source system that works this way, which is slightly odd, as it seems *much* nicer than an `unsubscribe` method.

A basic implementation:

```
public class WindowSystem {
  // This class represents an 'event source'.
  // you can subscribe to these.

  public interface MouseMovedHandler {
    void mouseAt(int x, int y);
  }

  @Value
  private static class HandlerContainer {
    WeakReference<Object> watch;
    MouseMovedHandler handler;
  }

  private final List<HandlerContainer> handlers =
    new ArrayList<HandlerContainer>();

  // NB: WARNING - this code is not threadsafe.
  // it needs to be - exercise left to the reader.
  public void subscribe(@NonNull Object watch, @NonNull MouseMovedHandler handler) {
    handlers.add(new HandlerContainer(new WeakReference<>(watch), handler));
  }

  void mainLoop() {
    // This code is called a lot by some separate thread managing
    // the window

    // ... the mouse is moved...
    fireMouseMoveEvent(x, y);
  }

  private void fireMouseMoveEvent(int x, int y) {
    var it = handlers.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      var c = it.next();
      if (c.getWatch().get() == null) {
        it.remove();
      } else {
        c.getHandler().mouseAt(x, y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's a lot more to it: Clearing stuff from the middle of enormous arraylists isn't efficient, sometimes you want separate threads for firing events, obviously the above is going to explode because you're modifying a single object from 2 separate threads (window loop, and whatever code is calling `.subscribe`), so it needs to use a relevant list type from `java.util.concurrent` (also check out `WeakHashMap` which is relevant to this kind of thing), or have some `synchronized` or `j.u.c.Lock` based code added, etc.

But, hopefully the idea is clear: That's how you 'auto unsubscribe' things based on the GC system.

Comment: Thank you @rzwitserloot, I see you used the phrase " is pointing at" in your answer, and I wanted to confirm if the way in which I'll rephrase it, correctly conveys your message:
"...a ref to whatever publisher is pointing at is part of this object." - to - "whatever reference the publisher is capturing is also part of this object." by this you mean: .add(localConsumer);

Or in the case: "instanceSubscriptorManager is pointing at an object that is not eligible for GC." - to - "instanceSubscriptorManager is capturing an object that is not eligible for GC." by this you mean: ...

Comment: because instanceSubscriptorManager is capturing publisher, which will survive this object life cycle, then this will NOT be GC'd.?

Comment: @Delark sounds like we're on the same page, yes. In java, all non-primitive fields are references. And reference is just another word for pointer. If an object is not GC-able and has a field that references X, X is also not GC-able (unless explicitly using Weak/SoftReference, WeakHashMap, etc).

Comment: Nitpicking: “whether code exists anywhere in the runtime that actually does this is irrelevant” is not correct. In principle, when a runtime can prove that no such access will ever happen (that is, even if such code exists but will never get executed [again]), and the object’s collection has no observable effect (i.e. no explicit finalizer), it is entitled to reuse the object’s memory. However, the difficulty is the proof, so in practice, you should not rely on it. The actual conclusion is that you should not rely on the assumption that it doesn’t get collected either.

Comment: I’d really like to see a real suggestion of where to store the `new Object()` you’re using as key. All places I can imagine will bring you back to square zero.

Comment: @Holger When you have fleeting listeners you tend to have fleeting something else too. For example, you create a new "ChatHandler" object for a long-lived HTTP connect session (where the server keeps the connection open for a few minutes). It registers the listener and maintains that object. Once the connection closes, this chathandler instance will die out at some point and take that object with it. Voila. In such a case the 'event source' needs to have weak linkage to the listener itself (I shouldn't have been so cavalier about that style).

Comment: Then, why isn’t the chathandler the even source in the first place? And when the key object became unreachable, the listener and everything referenced by it is still alive, because the necessary cleanup only happens when the collection of the key object will be detected within the event notification method. In other words, never, as in this scenario, the event notification method will never be called again.

Comment: The source would e.g. be the doorbell on your house that wants to tell all listeners 'hey, the doorbell just rang'. I can load a page, log in, and as long as that tab is open, there's a listener that is doing the job of conveying this info. If I close the tab, listener needs to go away: Hence, a fleeting listener. I think 'fleeting listeners' finds plenty of web results.

Comment: Yes, plenty of web results, but none related to programming. Anyway, your example of web page updates is not even remotely related to garbage collection. Neither does a garbage collector on a server notice whether a tab on the client has been closed nor can you add a weak listener to the client’s browser tab. In fact, the garbage collector doesn’t even understand that a socket object in the same JVM is closed. To the gc, it’s still a reachable object, so you need code actively checking the connected state and taking the right action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238177/discussion-between-rzwitserloot-and-holger).